# Show Medals after died in Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my Game I would like to have Medals like in Flappy Bird. So after the player die it should show the right medal. I made this code:

```
if self.score > 4{
                        let platinummedalTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "medal_platinum.png")
                        self.platinummedal = SKSpriteNode(texture: platinummedalTexture)
                        self.platinummedal.setScale(1)
                        self.platinummedal.zPosition = 120
                        self.platinummedal.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-65, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-0 - 10)
                        self.addChild(self.platinummedal)
                    }

                    if self.score > 3{
                        let goldmedalTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "medal_gold.png")
                        self.goldmedal = SKSpriteNode(texture: goldmedalTexture)
                        self.goldmedal.setScale(1)
                        self.goldmedal.zPosition = 120
                        self.goldmedal.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-65, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-0 - 10)
                        self.addChild(self.goldmedal)

                    }

                    if self.score > 2{
                        let silvermedalTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "medal_silver.png")
                        self.silvermedal = SKSpriteNode(texture: silvermedalTexture)
                        self.silvermedal.setScale(1)
                        self.silvermedal.zPosition = 120
                        self.silvermedal.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-65, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-0 - 10)
                        self.addChild(self.silvermedal)
                    }
                        if self.score > 1{
                            let bronzemedalTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "medal_bronze.png")
                            self.bronzemedal = SKSpriteNode(texture: bronzemedalTexture)
                            self.bronzemedal.setScale(1)
                            self.bronzemedal.zPosition = 120
                            self.bronzemedal.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame)-65, CGRectGetMidY(self.frame)-0 - 10)
                            self.addChild(self.bronzemedal)
                        }
```

In the game the score is higher to reach the medals but I put it on this Numbers for testing. So my problem is, if I get a score of 5 or higher it should display the Platinum Medal but it only displays the Gold one after 4 and higher.
The others works well. (2 = Bronze, 3 = silver, 4 = gold, 5 = gold -> wrong)

I dont know how to fix that problem and maybe someone of you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely better ways to do this, although since you want to know what is wrong this answer will be focused on your structure. Basically you have a conflict with the gold and platinum because there's nothing stopping the if statement from continuing down to the 4 even though the score is above that. What I would recommend is to use an `else if` statement after your first `if`:

```
var score : Int = 5

if score >= 5 {
    print("platinum")
}
else if score >= 4 {
    print("gold")
}
else if score >= 3 {
    print("silver")
}
else if score <= 2 {
    print("bronze")
}
```

Also you should use less than/greater along with equals to make sure that you are setting the right medal for the appropriate score. I personally like a bottom up approach (it's just the reverse of what you see above), but it's really personal preference in that regard. Here's an example:

```
var score : Int = 5

if score <= 2 {
    print("bronze")
}
else if score <= 3 {
    print("silver")
}
else if score <= 4 {
    print("gold")
}
else if score >= 5 {
    print("platinum")
}
```

Comment: PS: I left the last (no medal) as an exercise for you to understand how to fit in. Hint: It should be (less than or equal to 1) and you'll need to change the (<=2) to make it work properly.